# Dropdown menu with the dropdown-menu-right class does not align to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I have the following navbar structure (`{{ current_user.username }}` is from my templating system):

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
    <!-- navbar items -->
</ul>
<div class="dropdown show">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" style="color: inherit" href="#" id="dropdownLink" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        {{ current_user.username }}
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownLink">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <!-- etc -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

The dropdown part is aligned to the right of the screen, but clicking on it displays the dropdown menu going off the right of the screen, which the `dropdown-menu-right` class is supposed to prevent. Any ideas?

Minimal Codepen: https://codepen.io/Majora320/pen/jGwNrE

Comment: can you put it into a jsfiddle

Comment: @carinlynchin I added a codepen.io link

Comment: Great. I will take a look

Answer (score 1):

If you add the style

```
right: 0
```

to

```
 .dropdown-menu
```

style rule... it will do what you want.

Comment: But why does `dropdown-menu-right` not work? I believe that's what it's supposed to do.

Comment: not sure but docs say that it may need extra css for aligning properly. I'm guessing you have other styles that are affecting it...
    https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/

Comment: you'll have to have a new fiddle for me to look at.